# How to update deployment image on Azure Kubernetes Service with same image tag via an Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, continuous-deployment, azure-aks

I am trying to update my deployment with latest image content on Azure Kubernetes Service every time some code is committed to github . I have made a stage in my build pipeline to build and push the image on docker hub which is working perfectly fine. however in my release pipeline the image is being used as an artifact and is being deployed to the Azure Kubernetes Service , but the problem is that the image on AKS in not updating according to the image pushed on Docker Hub with latest code.

Right now each time some commit happens i have to manually update the image on AKS via the Command

*kubectl set image deployment/demo-microservice demo-microservice=customerandcontact:contact*

My Yaml File

[image]

Can anyone tell the error/changes if any in my yaml file to automatically update the image on AKS.

Comment: are you updating the container repository tags for each release ? you tag seems to be `:contact` so it does not change kubernetes wont do anything

Comment: Fro every release, you should create a new release tag

Comment: yes , I have tried creating a new tag using build id as customerandcontact:contact-#{Build.BuildId}# @Thomas but still its not updating

Comment: So are you re deploying the manifest after upating a new image ?

Comment: you need to do a kubectl apply or heml install depends what tool your using

Comment: did you link the artifact properly to the release pipeline ?

Comment: You seem to have attached an image of some sort to your question; can you replace it with the actual YAML file?

Comment: @Thomas what exactly do you mean by a manifest and also i am not deploying the manifest. and i am using kubectl apply command in my release pipeline as a separate stage.

Comment: @TusharMahajan yes , I have linked the yaml file as an artifact for release pipeline and my release pipeline is successful but the latest image is not updating.

Comment: @DavidMaze here is a link to it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YQHhSdOSXyt9KZABZRT3ln6WO-nslzpo/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

When you relese a new image to the container registry under the same tag it does not mean anything to Kubernetes. If you run `kubectl apply -f ...` and the image name and tag remains the same, it still won't do anything as there is no configuration change. There are two options:

1. Give a new tag on each build and change the `:contact` to the new tag in the yaml and run kubectl apply
2. For dev environment only (do not do it in Stage or Prod) leave the same tag (usually a tag `:latest` is used) and after a new image is deployed to registry run `kubectl delete pod demo-microservice`. Since you've set image pull policy to Always, this will cause Kubernetes pull a new image from the registry and redeploy the pod.

The second approach is a workaround just for testing.

Comment: If i will give new tag on each build then my docker hub will have 100's of images with a slight difference after some so what do you suggest of that ?

Comment: We use ACR script that deletes old tags. One marked for reaee can go to production registry or can get another tag following some pattern. Otherwise, how do you know which exact image passed qa and ymuat tests and is eligible for release?

Answer (score 1):

When you specify your image with the specific image tag Kubernetes will default container's `imagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent`, which means that image won't be pulled again, and previously pulled image will be deployed.

Kubernetes will change policy to `Always` only if tag is not present (which is effectively same as `latest` or if tag is set to `latest` explicitly.

Check what is actual imagePull policy on your Deployment template for particular container.

```
kubectl get pod demo-microservice -o yaml | grep imagePullPolicy -A 1
```

Try patching deployment

```
kubectl patch deployment demo-microservice -p 
 '{"spec": { "template" : 
  { "spec" : { "containers" : 
    [{"name" : "demo-microservice", 
    "image" : "repo/image:tag", 
    "imagePullPolicy": "Always" }]}}}}'
```

Make sure that `imagePullPolicy` for the container in question is set to `Always`.

Comment: Error Message : Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}  by running the kubectl patch command.

Comment: I just tried and it works for me, please check again

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me hours.